# Hurt animation interrupted during trap collision

Tags: unity-game-engine, 2d, game-development

I’m new to unity and game dev. I’m working to understand unity and 2D concepts and have encountered an issue with my player’s hurt animation. When the player gets hit by spikes, the hurt animation is supposed to play. However, it often gets interrupted by the previous animation state

Issue:

When the player gets hit by the spikes, the hurt animation starts but doesn’t always play fully. It gets interrupted by other animation states, regardless of the player’s current action.

Setup:

I have a PlayerMovement script that handles movement and animations using Rigidbody2D physics.
There’s also a PlayerHealth script that manages the player’s health and triggers the hurt animation when the player takes damage.
The spikes have their own script and collider. When the player collides with the spikes, the TakeDamage method from PlayerHealth is called.

Animator Configuration:

I have transitions set up in the Animator for the hurt state.
The hurt animation is triggered by a “hurt” trigger in the PlayerHealth script.
The transition from “Any State” to “Hurt” has the “Hurt” condition set up with exit time unchecked.
The transition from “Hurt” to “Idle” has exit time checked with an exit time set to 1.

[image: Player Animator]